# Page width bug when inserting AddThis code

Tags: width, addthis

I use AddThis on most pages on my website for sharing on social networks. Pages that have the AddThis code are very very wide, because of the AddThis code, as seen in the horizontal scroll bar (Please see example below). Removing the code fixes everything and the page width is back to normal. I can't seem to put my finger on the why this happens with the AddThis code. Please help!

Please click on link for example:
http://roshtof.co.il/events.php

Answer (score 0):

This is due to right to left language 
This is what make the problem in your code:
-10000px!important

After I remove it the scroll is fix.